# Php output array in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to output an array in twig, but I don't have enough experience in Twig.

I just don’t know how to output a non-associative array if the keys are index
Array 
$c_comments of such

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20:28 28:05:2019
            [1] => dokl
            [2] => 45645
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20:27 28:05:2019
            [1] => Alex
            [2] => 546
        )

)
```

```
    {% for vars.item.c_page in vars.item.comment %}
       <li>{{ vars.item.comment. }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

This is how I display an array in php, also needed in twig

```php
<div class="c_comments"><i>'.$c_comments[$i][0].' '.$c_comments[$i][1].' Wrote:</i><br>'.$c_comments[$i][2].'</div>';
```

Because of this, the template simply doesn't work.
So transfer the data to the template

```php
$item = ['first' => $number_f, 'two' => $number_t, 'comment' => $c_comments, 'c_page' => $c_page,'pagination' => $varPagination];
$this->registry['template']->set('item', $item);
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is `c_comments`, you can use this `for` loop :

```php
// PHP
$data = [
    [
        '20:28 28:05:2019',
        'dokl',
        45645,
    ],

    [
        '20:27 28:05:2019',
        'Alex',
        546,
    ]
];

echo $twig->render('index.html', ['c_comments' => $data]);
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
{% for key, comment in c_comments %}
    <i>{{ comment[0] }} {{ comment[1] }} Wrote: {{ comment[2] }}</i><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer